# Why can i get my mysqli_fetch_assoc working?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to make a php code where if I put in my database a URL, the code will pick up on that go to the URL and see what HTTP-code it gets but currently all it does is give me the HTTP-code 0 instead of the wright.

```
$username = "root";
$password = "luca170385";
$hostname = "localhost";

$dbhandle = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password)
or file_put_contents($filename, date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."Unable to connect to database", FILE_APPEND);
echo "Connect to MySQL<br>";

$selected = mysqli_select_db($dbhandle , "accounts")
or file_put_contents($filename, date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."Could not select database<br>", FILE_APPEND);
echo "Selected Database<br>";

$sql = "SELECT `address` FROM `url` WHERE `code` IS NULL";

if ($result = mysqli_query($dbhandle, $sql)){

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result));{
    printf ($row['address']);
    $output = "{$row['address']}";
    echo "{$row['address']}";
    $handle = curl_init($sql);
    curl_setopt($handle,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

    $response = curl_exec($handle);

    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    $update = "UPDATE url SET `code`= $httpCode WHERE `address` = $sql";
    echo "$update.<br>";
    echo "$handle.<br>";
    echo "$httpCode.<br>";

    mysqli_query($dbhandle, $update);
    echo "{$row['address']}";

    curl_close($handle);
    }
}else {
    echo 'Not working';
}
```

Comment: `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result));` <<< you see that semi-colon? It's an "end of statement" character and you wouldn't have gotten an error for it since it's a "valid" statement in PHP.

Comment: As per http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php *"As in C or Perl, PHP requires instructions to be terminated with a semicolon at the end of each statement. The closing tag of a block of PHP code automatically implies a semicolon; you do not need to have a semicolon terminating the last line of a PHP block. The closing tag for the block will include the immediately trailing newline if one is present."*

Comment: Btw, your query is failing you on top of the semi-colon. Echo that query and you'll see what it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the comments :-

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);// check all type of error
ini_set('display_errors',1);// display those errors
$username = "root";
$password = "luca170385";
$hostname = "localhost";

$dbhandle = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, "accounts");
/*or file_put_contents($filename, date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."Unable to connect to database", FILE_APPEND);
echo "Connect to MySQL<br>";*/// from where this $filename come from?

/*$selected = mysqli_select_db($dbhandle ,)
or file_put_contents($filename, date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."Could not select database<br>", FILE_APPEND);
echo "Selected Database<br>";*/ //not needed

$sql = "SELECT `address` FROM `url` WHERE `code` IS NULL";

if ($result = mysqli_query($dbhandle, $sql)){

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result)){ // remove ;
        printf ($row['address']);
        $output = $row['address']; // remove {} and ""
        echo $row['address']; // remove {} and ""
        $handle = curl_init($sql);
        curl_setopt($handle,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

        $response = curl_exec($handle);

        $httpCode = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        $update = "UPDATE url SET `code`= $httpCode WHERE `address` = $output"; // not $sql
        echo "$update.<br>";
        echo "$handle.<br>";
        echo "$httpCode.<br>";
        mysqli_query($dbhandle, $update);
        echo $row['address'];// remove {} and ""
        curl_close($handle);
    }
}else {
    echo 'Not working';
}
```

Comment: I decided not to post an answer (only comments), seeing their code is failing on more than one count.

Comment: `echo 'Not working';` won't help them here and should include proper error handling for the query and this for all queries.

Answer (score 2):

The `;` terminates the while, so it's empty.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result));
```

So you should just need to remove the `;`.

Comment: *"I think"* - you should remove that if you're not sure. I for one am sure.